# Regular Expression - Get partial string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of project names that I need some matching on.The list of projects could look something like this:

```
suzu
suzu-domestic
suzu-international
suzuran
suzuran-international
scorpion
scorpion-default
yada
yada-yada
etc
```

If the searched for project is `suzu`, I'd like to have the following result from the list:

```
suzu
suzu-domestic
suzu-international
```

but **not** anything containing `suzuran`. I also like to have the following match if the search for project is `suzuran`

```
suzuran
suzuran-international
```

but **not** anything containing `suzu`.

In C# code I have something that looks like similar to this:

```cs
String searchForProject = "suzu";
String regStr = @"THE_REGEX_GOES_HERE"; // The regStr will be in a config file
List<Project> projects = DataWrapper.GetAllProjects();
Regex regEx = new Regex(String.Format(regStr, searchForProject));
result = new List<Project>();
foreach (Project proj in projects)
{
  if (regEx.IsMatch(proj.ProjectName))
  {
    result.Add(proj);
  }
}
```

The question is, can I have a regexp that will enable me to get match on all exact project names, but not the ones that would get returned by a startWith equivalent?
(Today I have a `regStr = @"^({0})#"`, but this does not satisfy the above scenario since it gives more hits than it should)

I'd appreciate if someone can give me a hint in the right direction. Thanks !
Magnus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is actually

```
var regStr = @"^{0}\b";
```

The `^` anchor asserts the position at the beginning of string.
The `\b` pattern matches a location between a word and a non-word character, the start or end of string. You do not need to match the rest of string with `.*` since you are using `Regex.IsMatch`, it is a redundant overhead.

C# test code:

```
var projects = new List<string>() { "suzu", "suzu-domestic", "suzu-international", "suzuran", "suzuran-international", "scorpion", "scorpion-default", "yada", "yada-yada" };
var searchForProject = "suzu";
var regStr = @"^{0}\b"; // The regStr will be in a config file

var regEx = new Regex(String.Format(regStr, searchForProject));
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (var proj in projects)
{
    if (regEx.IsMatch(proj))
    {
        result.Add(proj);
    }
}
```

[image]

The `foreach` may be replaced with a shorter LINQ:

```
var result = projects.Where(s => regEx.IsMatch(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: Here is a link to the [**word boundary `\b`**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) reference at regular-expressions.info, just in case you are interested. If there is `_` instead of `-`, you will have to use something like `(?![\p{L}\p{N}])` instead of it, as `_` is a word character.

Comment: Excellent stribizhev !  I appreciate the extra _tutorial_ regarding LINQ and the reference to **word boundary** !

Comment: As for regex performance vs. pure LINQ approach: if you declare the regex as a `public static readonly` field in a static class with `RegexOptions.Compiled`, the speed will be comparable, and regex  will provide you better flexibility and control over your textual input and output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^suzu\b.*
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/bO5nB6/2)**

If you want `suzuran` just use:

```
^suzuran\b.*
```

Comment: `suzu\b.*` would catch "isuzu" :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"\b{0}\b.*"` if you want the match anywhere in the string (but not in the middle of a word), or `"^{0}\b.*"` if you only want it at the start.

See a [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbsuzu%5cb.*&i=suzu%0d%0asuzu-domestic%0d%0asuzu-international%0d%0asuzuran%0d%0asuzuran-international%0d%0ascorpion%0d%0ascorpion-default%0d%0ayada%0d%0ayada-yada%0d%0aetc&o=m) sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an elegant solution in one line with Linq and without regex, you can check this working solution (Demo on [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UkvgsQ)) :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        string input = "suzu";
        string s = @"suzu
suzu-domestic
suzu-international
suzuran
suzuran-international
scorpion
scorpion-default
yada
yada-yada";

        foreach (var line in ExtractLines(s, input))
            Console.WriteLine(line);    
    }

    // works if "-" is your delimiter.
    IEnumerable<string> ExtractLines(string lines, string input)
    {
        return from line in lines.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) // use to split your string by line
            let cleanLine = line.Contains("-") ? line.Split('-')[0] : line // use only the needed part
            where cleanLine.Equals(input) // check if the output match with the input
            select line; // return the valid line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With negative lookahead:

```
suzu(?!.*ran).*\b
```

This also uses \b for a word break